# How to get all values from database id to jcombobox?

Tags: java, mysql, database, user-interface, netbeans

I want to get all values from data ID.

I had done the following and just get the first value of ID data. Please help on how to get all values from it.

```
String sql = "select * from customer";
Connection cn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;  

public custmanagement() {
    initComponents();        
    setTitle("Customer Management");
    setResizable(false);      

    fillcombo();
}

private void fillcombo() {
    try {            
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dms_db", "root", "");
        ps=cn.prepareStatement(sql);  

        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {  
            String id = rs.getString("id");
            cboxid.addItem(id);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }        
}
```

I already know my problem. It is because I want to retrieve all data when choose id at jcombobox...here is my coding...

```
private void cboxidActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String id = cboxid.getSelectedItem().toString();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dms_db", "root", ""); 
        ps=cn.prepareStatement("select * from customer where id=?");
        ps.setString(1, id);
        rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            lblname.setText(rs.getString("name"));
            lblic.setText(rs.getString("ic"));
            lbladdress.setText(rs.getString("address"));
            lblgender.setText(rs.getString("gender"));
            lblpackage.setText(rs.getString("package"));
            lblphone.setText(rs.getString("phone"));               


        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

can someone help me what's wrong with this code...

Comment: 1. **Never** do this: `catch (Exception e) { }`. At least print out the stacktrace. Else how will you know if an exception ever occurs? 2. Time to do some debugging. Print out the results of the while loop to the console to see what data is in fact extracted.

Comment: I've done JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cboxid); out of while loop and it popup the same thing. Also, there are no exception occurs.